# Mod menu in review queues looks weird

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design, moderator-tools

When I try to use the mod link in the right-hand side of the review queue (close votes in this case), the mod menu is all greyed out and weird. Compare a 'normal' menu on a post:

> [image]

And one from review:

> [image]

It almost looks like the options are disabled, but they aren't. This is disorienting and confusing, can we fix it please?

Comment: +1 *purely* for those captions...

Comment: If only "convert to hamburger" was real... I'd certainly be using that option a *lot* more now than the existing one :)

Comment: Seriously? I'll eat the hamburger for lunch

Comment: I'm sure there's a "anonymize"-like button that converts strings to those ones.

Comment: @Braiam It's called 'inspect element'.

Comment: Meh, that's not funny...

Comment: _Goes to write userscript for fancy text_. WAIT. I can't test it out

Comment: @UniformsForSale I had that thought too... and I *can* test it out

Comment: @JonClements Where do you think Stack Exchange employees get their lunch every day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed and will be available in build 3737 for MSE/MSO, and build 2860 for other sites.